Why does the 'commandLine' property in WMI's 'win32_Process' return null for processes run by non-administrative users?
I have created a non-admin user, and trying to get details of Win32_Process but i'm either not getting any value or incorrect value for commandLine argument. I followed below steps to create the non-admin user and to give permissions to the non-admin user:
1.Non-admin User creation
2.Setting up the WMI configuration
3.Setting up the DCOM Access for non-admin user on the stand-alone Windows server
To Verify whether the issue is in our code or not I created a
What I have tried:
I have created a below .vbs script -
' VBScript to query Win32_Process
    ' Create the WMI service object
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
        
    ' Query Win32_Process
    Set colProcess= objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process")
    For Each objProcess In colProcess
        WScript.Echo "Process Name: " & objProcess.Name & ",Command line: " & objProcess.commandline
    Next
    

As I executed this script from Administrator user it is giving proper o/p as-executio through admin user
But for the non-admin user I'm not getting value of commandLine as below -
excution through non-admin user
So, Am I missing any property, or configuration for the non-admin user. Please guide.

That is the expected behavior. Command lines are considered privileged information.

Hi @GreagAskew Is there any permission or grant i can give to the non-admin user so that I will get the desired result Or I can make any improvement to the script?
